# Convert dictionary to sqlite database

Tags: java, android, regex, sqlite

I have dictionary in this format

```
Traditional Simplified [pin1 yin1] /English equivalent 1/equivalent 2/
^1          ^2         ^3          ^4                  ^5
```

For example

```
制 制 [A A zhi4] /to split the bill/to go Dutch/
^1 ^2 ^3        ^4                 ^5

T字帳 T字帐 [T zi4 zhang4] /T-account (accounting)/xyz abc
^1    ^2   ^3             ^4                     ^5
```

I want to convert this in sqlite database  TABLE WITH **5 Column**.
Trying to get solution with **Regex** didn't get success.

**EDIT :**

I want output like

```
制 制 [A A zhi4] /to split the bill/to go Dutch/

制 
制 
[A A zhi4] 
/to split the bill
/to go Dutch/
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What regex did you try? Note that [ and ] are special characters that must be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible regex (to be used per line) could be

```
(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[([^\[\]]*)\]\s*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)
```

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "(\\S+)       # one or more non-whitespace characters -> group 1\n" +
    "\\s+         # one or more whitespace characters\n" +
    "(\\S+)       # one or more non-whitespace characters -> group 2\n" +
    "\\s+         # one or more whitespace characters\n" +
    "\\[          # [\n" +
    "([^\\[\\]]*) # anything except [] -> group 3\n" +
    "\\]          # ]\n" +
    "\\s*/        # optional whitespace, then /\n" +
    "([^/]*)      # anything except / -> group 4\n" +
    "/            # /\n" +
    "([^/]*)      # anything except / -> group 5", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

After a match, the five groups will be in the `Matcher` object's `.group(n)` (for `1 <= n <= 5`).

Comment: Thanks for answer @Tim I got 5 as matcher group count, can you please tell me how to get 5 values

Comment: Just iterate over the matcher object (`for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++)`, and you'll get the values as `matcher.group(i)`.

Comment: yes have tried same getting this `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

Comment: Okey got solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12911620/1289716) Thanks for your help, thanks a lot... @Tim.