# Unable to match second group with Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Having the following `String`: `|mykey:myvalue|` being `mykey` and `myvalue` any random set of characters, I'm trying to retrieve the `myvalue` part with the following regex:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("^\\|(.*):(.*)\\|$")

String secondGroup = REGEX.matcher(pivot).group(2)
```

However, it will throw an exception as `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`.

How can I match the previous string and return the second value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rationale for Matcher throwing IllegalStateException when no 'matching' method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911504/rationale-for-matcher-throwing-illegalstateexception-when-no-matching-method-i) In short you likely need to call `matcher.find()` before `.group(2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, you need to call the `find()` method on the `Matcher` object to perform the match before accessing the groups and `find()` method is called on the `matcher` object to perform the match. If a match is found, you can then access the second group using `matcher.group(2)`. If no match is found, you can handle it accordingly.

check this out :

```
private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("^\\|(.*):(.*)\\|$");
Matcher matcher = REGEX.matcher(pivot);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String secondGroup = matcher.group(2);
    System.out.println(secondGroup);
} else {
    System.out.println("No match found.");
}
```